# enabling a feature when using libraries

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-tokio, rust-futures

I'm trying to use `DefaultAsyncInterface` of [tunio](https://github.com/GamePad64/tunio/) which depends on `tokio` feature ([here](https://github.com/GamePad64/tunio/blob/7aae287b3320d490d363b73ae359a8848a02cb00/src/lib.rs#L20))

I have added `tunio` with `async-tokio` feature in `Cargo.toml`:

```ini
[dependencies]
env_logger = "0.10.0"
etherparse = "0.13.0"
futures = "0.3.25"
netconfig = "0.4.0"
tokio = { version = "1.24.1", features = ["full"] }
tunio = { version = "0.3.0", features = ["async-tokio"] }
```

and imported it:

```rust
use tunio::{DefaultDriver,DefaultAsyncInterface};
```

but when I try to build I get:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `tunio::DefaultAsyncInterface`
 --> src/main.rs:7:27
  |
7 | use tunio::{DefaultDriver,DefaultAsyncInterface};
  |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |                           |
  |                           no `DefaultAsyncInterface` in the root
  |                           help: a similar name exists in the module: `DefaultInterface`
```

It seems the `async-tokio` feature is not used
What is the problem?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but `tokio` and `async-tokio` are different feature names, no? The code you linked uses `tokio`. Where does `async-tokio` come from?

Comment: @Brian: yes that was the problem, it seems this crate has inconsistency between documentation and repository. documentation said I need add [`async-tokio`](https://docs.rs/crate/tunio/0.3.0/features) and with cargo there were no `tokio` feature, now I tried to install from git and now there is a `tokio` feature and everything works,  thank you

Comment: Glad to hear that resolved it! It always hurts when it's something so trivial